# How can I use FactoryBot in db/seeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, seed

Is it possible to do this?

If so, how can you do it?

Note: FactoryBot was previously named FactoryGirl

Comment: db/seeds.rb should contain production specific core data that your site needs to run. Factories should only be used in your tests, helping you execute operations in isolation. Are you just trying to make your db/seeds shorter or something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(This answer works in rails 3.0.7)

I found the catch is how you set up the `Gemfile` - you need to do something along the lines of

```ruby
gem 'factory_girl'

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

We found problems having `factory_girl_rails` outside of the `:test` environment, which we didn't manage to get to the bottom of (maybe something to do with the way rails does class caching?)

Once that is done, I like to actually load data from a library in lib, something like...

```ruby
require 'factory_girl'
require 'spec/factories/user_factory'

module Seeds

  class SampleUsers

    def self.run
    u = Factory(:user)
  end
end
```

And then running this method from within `db:seed` using

```ruby
Seeds::SampleUsers.run
```

Comment: See hubble's comment on Michael's answer for an alternate way of making the Gemfile work. It seems factory_girl_rails is safe to require in db/seeds but shouldn't be auto-required by Rails through Bundler. To keep that from happening hubble sets :require => false.

Comment: Great answer! Just what I needed. I found that I would get errors if I had the two require statements. So I don't have them in my implementation.

Comment: In Rails 4, this is no longer necessary: you can get away with

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'

Then just require 'factory_girl_rails' in lib/tasks/sample_data.rake.

Answer (score 31):

All you need to do is add `require 'factory_bot_rails'` to the `db/seeds.rb` file. This will give you access to your factories.

Note: Gem was previously called FactoryGirlRails

Comment: This is great, but make sure :require => false is in your Gemfile for factory_girl_rails, otherwise it causes initialization dependency issues when you try to db:migrate and the factories represent models you haven't migrated yet. -- And then you'll need to require 'factory_girl_rails' in your spec_helper after that.

Answer (score 18):

Josh Clayton, the maintainer of FactoryGirl, [recommends against using FactoryGirl in your seeds file](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory_girl-for-seed-data/). He suggests using plain ActiveRecord instead.

Comment: One good argument for wanting to use Factory Girl in seeds is that our ActiveRecord seeds keep breaking every time someone updates the API. It breaks without warning. To guard against that we want the seed file to be test covered. Factory Girl can help with both seeding and testing.

Comment: I never quite understood that article.. My guess is they refer to using it only for that purpose. If you already have several factories used for testing, that you already keep up to date it makes a lot of sense to reuse them instead of rewriting that logic.

Answer (score 14):

in db/seeds.rb

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'

10.times do
  FactoryGirl.create :user
end
```

Comment: FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 10)

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 5.2.6, you can create factories in your `db/seeds.rb` file. Add `include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods` at the top of your `seeds.rb` file. Below that line, you can create your factories – i.e. `user1 = create(:user)`.

```rb
# db/seeds.rb
include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

user1 = create(:user)
```

Comment: This works great!  The only potential consideration is to have your factories in some other location than [`spec/factories`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#definition-file-paths)

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the following code into your spec_helper.rb, and it make some instances of the data you want (in this case "products" from the yaml file):

```
seeds_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds.yml')
config = YAML::load_file(seeds_file)
config["products"].each do |product|
  FactoryGirl.create(:product, product) if !Product.find_by_name(product['name'])    
end
```